# notation meaning - braces in the variable's subscript

Tags: notation

I am trying to understand the meaning of the braces in the subscript of a variable. I've encountered it in a paper [Distributional Reinforcement Learning with Quantile Regression](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10044), page 5

Does it mean "as long as the condition is met"? But what is then the alternative expression, when the condition is *not* met? Have a look at equation (12):

[image]

Do I read the equation 12 correctly:

- the $\theta_i$ becomes equal to its current value plus ( $\tau_i$ minus $\delta$ **in cases where** $r + \gamma z'$ is less than the current $\theta_i$ ), scaled by $\alpha$

Or do these { } braces have another interpretation? Are they used to denote a piece-wise function?

Comment: They introduce the notation at the end of page 3 in the paper. They say
"$\delta_{z}$ denotes a Dirac at $z\in\mathbb{R}$". Did you see that?
The same notation with braces seems to indicate the same thing for a set of points instead of a single point.

Comment: Thank you, I am pretty sure that's was the right answer. I had an additional discussion with peers and expression seems to mean "1 when {condition is true}, 0 otherwise"